# Selecting one checkbox each table row

Tags: java, jquery, checkbox

```
  out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>\n"
            + "<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n"
            + "<script>\n"
            + "$(function() {\n"
            + "  $('input[type=\"checkbox\"]')\n"
            + "    .on('change', function(){$('input[type=\"checkbox\"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);});\n"
            + "});\n"
            + "</script>\n"
            + "</head>");
    out.println("<body>");   

   while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Object o = itr.next();
            Element vraag = (Element) o;

            StringBuffer row = new StringBuffer("<tr>");

            row.append("<td>" + vraag.getChildText("VRAAG") + "</td>");
            String antwoord = vraag.getChildText("INVOERMOGELIJKHEID");

            if (antwoord.equals("tweecheckbox")) {
                row.append("<td>" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"tweecheckbox\" value=\"0\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"tweecheckbox\" value=\"1\">" + "</td>");
            } else if (antwoord.equals("driecheckbox")) {
                row.append("<td>" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"driecheckbox\" value=\"0\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"driecheckbox\" value=\"1\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"driecheckbox\" value=\"2\">");
            } else if (antwoord.equals("viercheckboxNT")) {
                row.append("<td>" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"viercheckboxNT\" value=\"0\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"viercheckboxNT\"value=\"1\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\"name=\"viercheckboxNT\"value=\"2\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\"name=\"viercheckboxNT\"value=\"3\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\"name=\"viercheckboxNT\"value=\"\">" + "</td>");
            } else if (antwoord.equals("vijfcheckbox")) {
                row.append("<td>" + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"vijfcheckbox\" value=\"0\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\"name=\"vijfcheckbox\"value=\"1\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\"name=\"vijfcheckbox\"value=\"2\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\"name=\"vijfcheckbox\"value=\"3\">" + "<input type=\"checkbox\"name=\"vijfcheckbox\"value=\"4\">");
            } else if (antwoord.equals("tekstvak")) {
                row.append("<td>" + "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"tekstvak\" SIZE=\"11\" MAXLENGTH=\"20\">");
            } else {
                row.append("<td>" + antwoord);
            }

            out.println(row.toString());

        }
```

In the code above, I'm trying to make a form out of an xml-file in a java servlet.

The form is creating and working. However, I would like to check one checkbox every row. At the moment I can only select one checkbox in the whole form.

I think the creating of checkboxes in the while loop is the problem. However, I have to create 88 rows, all with 5 checkboxes, for this form. Is there a way to do this, but will be able to select one checkbox every row?

Answer (score 1):

To check the first checkbox or every row you can try,,

```
$(function() {
   $('tr input[type="checkbox"]:first').prop('checked',true);
});
```

And to check every column's first checkbox try,

```
$(function() {
   $('tr td input[type="checkbox"]:first').prop('checked',true);
});
```

Comment: Are we sure JS is what the OP is asking for?

Comment: **i would like to check one checkbox every row.** What is it mean?

Comment: It's not that i want to select the first checkbox of every row. I would like to select one of the five checkboxes in every row.

Comment: Ok. I personally think you could do it in Java (with a little bit more investigation). Otherwise, this answer is good.

Comment: **Alternatively,** it can be done in Java by adding `checked="checked"` in the very first checkbox of a column, as you are using `if-elseif` so no repetitive check wil apply to your checkbox.